# Magento 1.9.2.1 unable to print invoice PDF

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, zend-framework

To give a bit of background, I've upgraded my Magento from 1.4.1 to 1.9.1 then to 1.9.2.1. Since then I've applied all of the patches needed including the patch that address's php 5.4. I've checked all frontend functionality through on my site and it's working fine. All of my dashboard function work fine apart from the print invoice

Here is an example of the url

siteurl/index.php/admin/sales_order_invoice/view/invoice_id/10058/order_id/10258/key/website-key

But instead of downloading the invoice I get a webpage with a lot of text that looks like it's firing a long line of error code. It looks to be over 5000 lines long.

```
Array ( [0] => Zend_Pdf_Page Object ( [_dictionary:protected] => Zend_Pdf_Element_Object Object ( [_value:protected] => Zend_Pdf_Element_Dictionary Object ( [_items:Zend_Pdf_Element_Dictionary:private] => Array ( [Type] => Zend_Pdf_Element_Name Object ( [value] => Page [_parentObject:Zend_Pdf_Element:private] => ) [LastModified] => Zend_Pdf_Element_String Object ( [value] => D:20150910113836+00'00' [_parentObject:Zend_Pdf_Element:private] => ) [Resources] => Zend_Pdf_Element_Dictionary Object ( [_items:Zend_Pdf_Element_Dictionary:private] =>
```

This is just a small snippet of the code on my page. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Is this an error message? It looks like a `print_r` somewhere in your code.

I would assume you changed the pdf creation and left somewhere a `print_r`

Comment: Yes I believe this is an error message. It's not a normal Magento error message as it just starts with "Array". I will amend the question to include that this is an error. I will check for a print_r do you know what file it could be in.

Comment: no clue which file, `grep -R` is your friend